# PushSharp APNS notification error The function requested is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I'm using PushSharp 4.0.10
In the OnNotificationFailed event of the Apns broker, I get "The function requested is not supported" exception. There is my Broker creator

```
private static ApnsServiceBroker CreateApnsBroker(string certificate)
{
    // Configuration (NOTE: .pfx can also be used here)
    var config = newApnsConfiguration(
        ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox,
        certificate,
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cert_Passwd"],
        false);

    // Create a new broker
    var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

    // Wire up events
    apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
    {
        aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
        {
            // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
            if (ex is ApnsNotificationException notificationException)
            {
                // Deal with the failed notification
                var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                Logger.Info($"Apple Notification Failed:
                    ID={apnsNotification.Identifier},
                    Code={statusCode}",
                    ex);
            }
            else
            {
                // Inner exception might hold more useful information
                // like an ApnsConnectionException
                Logger.Info($"Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason:
                    {ex.InnerException}",
                    ex);
            }
                // Mark it as handled
                return true;
            });
    };

    apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
    {
        Logger.Info($"Apple Notification Sent for device {notification.DeviceToken}");
    };

    return apnsBroker;
}
```

Send notification

```
private static void QueueNotification(
    ApnsServiceBroker apnsBroker,
    string deviceToken,
    string payload)
{
    // Queue a notification to send
    apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
    {
        DeviceToken = deviceToken,
        Payload = JObject.Parse(payload),
        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
    });
}
```

When I stop the broker in OnNotificationFailed catch exception. In PushSharp and in my code I using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Using .p12 certificate for voip notifications, it's added in mmc
What's my mistake?

Comment: I have the same issue. Few days ago everything was working fine. Today it is not. Have you updated the windows 10? I did...

Answer (score 1):

I clone PushSharp repo, compile local dll, change project links and it's work, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package in Nuget is not up to date with the code in Github. The latest version in Github supports TLS 1.2, which recently became mandatory. Therefore, the only solution is to clone the repo, build it yourself and add a reference to the newly built DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix:

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Put this in your application_startup or startup.cs